# Next / Previous post in a single category

Tags: posts, navigation

I have a blog with two categories of posts that I don't want 'mixing' with the rest of the posts for purposes of the single post navigation.  I've been able to modify the next/previous for all the other posts but I'm trying to modify for these two categories.

Using the parameters of next_post_link I can set in_same_term to true.  The trouble is many of these posts have multiple categories assigned.  What I'm trying to do is restrict the previous / next links to only the one cateogry.  So, in this case the category I'm trying to stay in is ID 152.  If the current post is in 152, 12, 19 I want the next and previous link to be to a post in category 152, not 12 or 19.  Limiting the term (5th parameter) to 152 didn't work.  Any ideas?

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of `in_same_term` and `excluded_terms`. First of all, you have the ID of the category you want to display post from. Next, get all the id of the category of the post by using [wp_get_post_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)

You can iterate through the returned terms and build an array of terms that you want to exclude. That should do the trick.

Comment: I don't think that will work.  I want to display any post with category 152 as one of it's categories.  It could have 152 and 12 or 152 and 17.  If it does I don't want to exclude cats 12 & 17, but if I don't exclude them it will display posts with only 12 or 17.  Am I missing something?  I believe I understand the logic but I'm not positive.